# Node Version Trouble deploying React app onto GCP

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble deploying my React app onto GCP, and keep bumping into this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rJjE.png)

It's saying:

1. Your package.json does not specify a supported Node.js version.  Please pin your application to a major version of the Node.js runtime.
2. Application detection failed: Error: node.js checker: Neither "start" in the "scripts" section of "package.json" nor the "server.js" file were found.

My package.json doesn't have node.js but this is what it looks like:
I've manually included in my dependency: Node: 12.18.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG9Uv.png)

I'm not sure what to do anymore. I've changed the yaml file to:
Nodejs, Nodejs10, Nodejs12

I've also changed the package.json file to:
nothing, Node 10, 12...

Anyone ran into this and know how to work around it? I'm using Yarn as my package manager for build but i doubt that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this

```
{
  "name": "@eneto/rest-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "Ernesto Jara Olveda",
    "email": "ernesto.jara06@gmail.com",
    "url": "https://www.enetojarapro.com"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
 .....
```

if not at the root of your project creacte a file call `.nvmrc`
inside of it add the node version you have example v12.16.1 if your OS is Linux/Unix just type this

```
$ $(node -v)>>.nvmrc
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you specifying it incorrectly in `package.json`.

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#nodejs_version) suggests that you should do it like this:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x.x"
  }
}
```